# How to align text in the center of an element without considering floated elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok i got this markup

```
<th class="ai1ec-weekday <?php if( $day['today'] ) echo 'ai1ec-today' ?>">
    <span class="ai1ec-weekday-date"><?php
    echo Ai1ec_Time_Utility::date_i18n( 'l', $date, true );
    ?> </span>
</th>
```

which produces this output as the span has `text-align: center`

[image]

now i want to add a button which is floated to the right

```
<th class="ai1ec-weekday <?php if( $day['today'] ) echo 'ai1ec-today' ?>">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <button class="btn ai1ec-reveal-events"><?php _e( 'Reveal all events', AI1EC_PLUGIN_NAME ) ?></button> 
    </div>
    <span class="ai1ec-weekday-date"><?php
    echo Ai1ec_Time_Utility::date_i18n( 'l', $date, true );
    ?> </span>
</th>
```

and this is what i get

[image]

what i would like to obtain is that mondais still centered as it was before, but i would like to do that without using absolute positioning (if it's possible, of course)

the CSS ( i mean other than bootstrap CSS )

```
.ai1ec-week-view th .ai1ec-weekday-date,
.ai1ec-oneday-view th .ai1ec-weekday-date {
  font-size: 10.5pt !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
.ai1ec-week-view th .ai1ec-weekday-day {
  font-size: 9pt !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
.ai1ec-month-view th, .ai1ec-oneday-view th {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: Could we see all the CSS? (Or is that in Twitter Bootstrap?)

Comment: why you don't want to use the absolute position?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well yes, it's twitter bootstrap, i've added what i think it's important, there are a lot of overrides and so on

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan because it wouldn't resize correctly i think

Comment: you could use position absolute after a given breakpoint (with a mediaquery) and a static position on mobile-first style.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan can't i use relative positioning somehow?

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: when an element is relatively positioned, it still affects page layout in the same way it would have done if it wasn’t positioned. So it’ll still cause the different center point for text aligning.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti see if my answer can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this approach: http://jsbin.com/uxejes/1/edit
(tested only on Fx18 and Chrome)

relevant css

```
button {
  float: right; 
  margin-right: -100%;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
}

span {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

the button (with `position: relative`) won't affect the position of the text contained inside the `span` element